# Deploying a contract that inherits GnosisSafe from another smart contract

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, gnosis-safe, gnosis

relative beginner to both Solidity and Gnosis here, so please bear with me :)

I have the following contract:

```
contract MyCustomWallet is GnosisSafe {
    using GnosisSafeMath for uint256;
    
    constructor(...args) {
         ... set up GnosisSafe
         ... deploy and add several modules and guards
    }
}
```

In an ideal world, I would like the contract to be shown in the Gnosis UI **and** a custom UI that I'm making.

What would be the best way to go about deploying something like this? Would it be through a `GnosisSafeProxyFactory`?

Answer (score 4):

If the goal is to deploy a Safe with custom modules and guards, you don't necessarily need a separate contract to do that. When deploying a Safe, there's a distinct `initializer` parameter to setup modules during the creation:
[SafeProxyFactory::createProxyWithNonce](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/13a5d892677254edc3640fd9fbb8e03ded2832d2/contracts/proxies/SafeProxyFactory.sol#L49)

[Safe::setup](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/13a5d892677254edc3640fd9fbb8e03ded2832d2/contracts/Safe.sol#L88-L89)

With the guard, it's a little more complicated because it's not possible to set up one at the creation time, but you can trigger a separate transaction after the creation or create a custom factory contract.

It is not possible to extend the singleton contract (contract that holds the logic for the Safe) and keep the UI compatibility because it will result in different singleton, and we currently only index Safes that are using singleton contracts by the Safe project

Comment: you can use the initializer also to add a guard

Comment: Thanks for the info! Just a few more questions from my end:

Comment: Hi @Richard! How would you use the initializer to add a guard? `addGuard` can be called only from a `GnosisSafe` instance itself, which means we need to add its own address and delegatecall data to the initializer data. The address needs to be predicted and included into the data affecting the address generation. Is that possible?