# Deploying Gnosis Safe & setting up guards / modules in one transaction

Tags: solidity, gnosis-safe

I'm a solidity developer for Decent DAO working on building Fractal, a framework that leverages Gnosis Safes & Zodiac.

Ideally, we would like to be able to deploy a Gnosis Safe and setup guards / modules all in one transaction.

I've looked at doing this through the `setupModules` function, but it doesn't seem possible to use this function since it executes through a delegateCall, so the `msg.sender` won't be the Gnosis Safe, so this function won't be able to call `setGuard` or `enableModule`.

I've also looked at using the `createProxyWithCallback` function within the `GnosisSafeProxyFactory`. However, the context for `msg.sender` here will still not be the Gnosis Safe, so doesn't seem like this could work either.

Is what we're trying to do here possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set up module during safe deployment using the initializer as described in this answer! [Deploying a contract that inherits GnosisSafe from another smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/120050/deploying-a-contract-that-inherits-gnosissafe-from-another-smart-contract)
Hopefully this helps :D