# Deploy Gnosis Safe and add transaction guard in one atomic transaction

Tags: gnosis-safe

Is it possible to achieve this? I am trying to deploy a wallet using a static admin signer for users, so it is most ideal that I can deploy the safe for them using the admin signer but restrict the scope of functions callable to that signer - e.g. only addOwner is allowed. Has anyone tried this?

Comment: Please see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/120050/deploying-a-contract-that-inherits-gnosissafe-from-another-smart-contract